# Why do we need to perform bitwise AND to a bit field when branching inside a switch statement

Tags: javascript, typescript, bitmask

I don't really understand why we need to apply bitwise `AND` by `BindingFlags.Types` in the code below:

```
switch (binding.flags & BindingFlags.Types) {
    case BindingFlags.TypeElementAttribute:
      setElementAttribute(view, binding, renderNode, binding.ns, name, value);
      break;
    case BindingFlags.TypeElementClass:
      setElementClass(view, renderNode, name, value);
      break;
    case BindingFlags.TypeElementStyle:
      setElementStyle(view, binding, renderNode, name, value);
      break;
    case BindingFlags.TypeProperty:
      const bindView = (def.flags & NodeFlags.ComponentView &&
                        binding.flags & BindingFlags.SyntheticHostProperty) ?
          elData.componentView :
          view;
      setElementProperty(bindView, binding, renderNode, name, value);
      break;
  }
```

Here's `BindingFlags` definition:

```
export const enum BindingFlags {
  TypeElementAttribute = 1 << 0,
  TypeElementClass = 1 << 1,
  TypeElementStyle = 1 << 2,
  TypeProperty = 1 << 3,
  SyntheticProperty = 1 << 4,
  SyntheticHostProperty = 1 << 5,
  CatSyntheticProperty = SyntheticProperty | SyntheticHostProperty,

  // mutually exclusive values...
  Types = TypeElementAttribute | TypeElementClass | TypeElementStyle | TypeProperty
}
```

Can someone please clarify?

Comment: That depends on what values `binding.flags` can assume. Can you tell us, please? Do you think the bitmask is superfluous or what in particular do you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't really understand why we need to apply logical AND by BindingFlags.Types in the code below:

It's a *bitwise* AND (`&`), not a logical one (`&&`).

You need it in order to filter out the other bits (`SyntheticProperty`, for instance). `BindingFlags.Type` only includes the `TypeXYZ` bits.

For instance, if `binding.flags` has both `SyntheticProperty` (0b00010000) and `TypeElementClass` (0b00000010), its value is 0b00010010. Since the `switch` needs to match just the flags for types, it uses `BindingFlags.Types` (0b00001111) with `&` to mask out the non-types values. 0b00010010 & 0b00001111 is 0b0001000, so it matches the `SyntheticProperty` case.